# Classcast exception on mocking JAX-WS proxy

Tags: java, spring, mocking, jax-ws, mockito

Classcast on mocking JAX-WS proxy

I try to use the JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean in Spring (3.2.2 Release), but it fails when I try to mock the port in my unit test. The reason for the classcast exception is that I need to cast the proxy to a Bindingprovider.

I tried to add the withSettings().extraInterfaces, but I get the same exception. 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mockito/YM5EF0x90_4

Has anyone any suggestions to resolve my pain in the ass or doing the mocking of the port in some other way? The only reason I added the JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean was to be able to unit test without doing the WS call.

ApplicationContext-beans:

```
<bean id="port" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock" >
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="name of the portType class" />
</bean>
```

WSHelper:

```
    import com.sun.xml.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties;
    import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;

       @Resource
        private  ThePortTypeClass port;
    …

       BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port; 
...
```

Portfolioimpl:

```
REQUEST request=  RequestHelper.getRequest(vo);
ThePortTypeClass port =wSHelper.getPort();
RESPONSE response = null;
response = port.wSMethod(request);
```

unit test:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext.xml"})
public class PortfolieTest {

@Resource
    private ThePortTypeClass port;

    @Resource
    private WSHelper wsHelper;



    @Autowired
    Portfolio portfolio;

    @Before
    public void setup(){

        RESPONSE response = new RESPONSE();
        …
        port=mock(ThePortTypeClass.class, withSettings().extraInterfaces(BindingProvider.class));
        when(port.method(any(REQUEST.class))).thenReturn(response);

    }

    @Test
    public void update() {
                assertEquals(true, portfolio.update(someParameters));
}
}
```

**Update:**

I don't think the issue is different versions of the Bindingprovider. 
When I do the following change to the proxy bean it's able to do the cast and does the ws call.

```
  <bean id="port" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="ThePortTypeClass" />
        <property name="namespaceUri" value="nm" />
        <property name="serviceName" value="theServicename" />
        <property name="endpointAddress" value="theUrl" />
        <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="theUrl" />
    </bean>
```

The JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean does implements the Bindingprovider interface so that it's able to cast the proxy to a bindingprovider. But when I mock the object it is no longer of a type that implements the BindingProvider.

Comment: Is the BindingProvider it actually _is_ the same BindingProvider as your classloader sees?  In other words, do you have two copies of BidningProvider present in your JVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out my unit test looked more like a integration test..

Changed the test to the following to make it work:

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PortfolieTest {

    @InjectMocks
    Portfolio portfolio = new PortfolioImpl();

    @Mock
    private thePortType port;

    @Mock    
    private WSHelper wsHelper = new WSHelper();

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Feil, MalformedURLException, DocumentException {

        RESPONSE response = new RESPONSE();
        …

        when(wsHelper.gePort(someParameters).thenReturn(port);
        when(port.wsmethod(any(REQUEST.class))).thenReturn(response);

    }

    @Test
    public void update() throws MalformedURLException, DocumentException {
        assertEquals(true, portfolio.update(someParameters));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what I tried and working.

1. Create a abstract class/ interface

   ```
   public interface AbstractPZGetEmployeeDataV3 extends PZGetEmployeeDataV3Port, BindingProvider {
   }
   ```
2. Mocked the above with Inject

   ```
   @Spy
   AbstractPZGetEmployeeDataV3 spyPort;
   ```
3. Add more meat to it

   ```
   Mockito.lenient().when(pZGetEmployeeDataV3_Service.getPZGetEmployeeDataV3SOAPAPIGEEDEV()).thenReturn(spyPort);
   GetAllGenericEmployeeDataResponse soapResp = new GetAllGenericEmployeeDataResponse();
   soapResp.setEmploymentStatusCode("S");
   soapResp.setLastName("LastNAme");
   Mockito.lenient().when(spyPort.getAllGenericEmployeeData(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(soapResp);
   ```